# How do I share NSNumberFormatter over multiple NIB files?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding

I'm working on an `NSPersistentDocument` based app that has a per-document currency setting.

Preferably, I would like to use a single `NSNumberFormatter` `currencyFormatter` for all my NIB files, but there doesn't seem to be any easy way to bind, say, `NSTextField` `formatter` to `document.currencyFormatter` or something similar.

I'm pretty sure it is possible to do this using code, adding bindings manually, but it is quite a bit of work since I have many fields using the currency formatter.

What is the best option to share the currency formatter across multiple NIB files?

Comment: That is a standard formatter isn't it?  So don't you just set it up using the IB binding inspector of each field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I suggest two ways:

1. Subclass the NSNumberFormatter and make it be a singleton (the init method return the same object every time is called).Then drag an object in every xib file and set it's class to the name of the NSNumberFormatter subclass;
2. Just use the bindings inspector to bind each formatter to document.currencyFormatter.

PS: I'm not sure if I completely understand what you're asking, tell me if one of these would be a valid solution to you.